# Parameter Not valid error when adding a third series

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I am automating a chart in Excel from PowerShell.

```
$ExcelObject=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelWorkbook=$ExcelObject.WorkBooks.Open("$OutputFolder\$MySpreadsheet.xlsx")  
$ActiveWorksheet=$ExcelWorkbook.WorkSheets.item("Results")
$ActiveChart=$ActiveWorksheet.Shapes.AddChart().Chart
$ActiveChart.chartType = 73
$TableRange="P11:P15"
$currentRange=$ActiveWorksheet.Range($TableRange)
$ActiveChart.SetSourceData($currentRange)
$ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Visible
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name="Series1"
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues="=Results!`$M`$11:`$M`$15"
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values="=Results!`$P`$11:`$P`$15"

$ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Visible
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name="Series2"
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues="=Results!`$M`$11:`$M`$15"
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values="=Results!`$Z`$11:`$Z`$15"

$ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Visible
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Name="Series3"
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues="=Results!`$M`$11:`$M`$15"
$ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values="=Results!`$W`$11:`$W`$15"
```

However, I get "Parameter not valid" on any command in the FullSeriesCollection(3) set. I switched the content around and no matter what block is series 3, Excel returns that error. If I build the chart from a macro and switch to VBA, it makes the same reference to FullSeriesCollection(3) and works fine manually within Excel.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
```

Needed to be

```
$ActiveChart.SeriesCollection().NewSeries.Invoke()
```

The chart automatically had two, so the third not being there was due to that command not actually creating a series.

Comment: Go figure. And here I was throwing together an answer based on `Add` instead of `NewSeries`.